# Valor do dado em determinada Data

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela numa base de dados postgresql que contém o nome do funcionário, a data em que começou a trabalhar e a data em que saiu da empresa, caso o funcionário ainda esteja na empresa este campo tem valor nulo. Sabendo disso, gostaria de saber quantas pessoas estavam trabalhando em uma data pré-determinada, ex:

Gostaria de saber quantas pessoas trabalhavam na empresa em janeiro de 2021.

Não sei por onde começar, em algumas tentativas consegui o número de contratações e dispensas por mês, mas preciso mostrar esse valor acumulado por mês, em outra coluna.

Espero ter me feito entender, vou deixar o último sql que tenho aqui.

```
select referencia, sum(admitidos) from
(
select 
    date_trunc('month', data_admissao) as referencia,
    count(*) as admitidos,
    desligados
from
    ponto_mais_relatorio_colaboradores
group by 
    data_admissao
union all

select  
    date_trunc('month', data_desligamento) as referencia,
    admitidos,
    count(*)*-1 as desligados
from 
    ponto_mais_relatorio_colaboradores
group by 
    data_desligamento    
) as referencia

join calendario_aux on calendario_aux.ano_mes = referencia

group by referencia
order by referencia
```

Comment: *"Espero ter me feito entender,"* mais ou menos, acho que para entendermos melhor seria mais eficiente se colocasse: estrtura das tabelas, um pequeno exemplo de dados (2 ou 3 linhas por exemplo) e como espera o resultado

Answer (score -1):

Seleccione e contabilize todos os funcionários cuja dada de entrada seja anterior a dada proposta, e a data de saída seja não nula e seja posterior a data proposta;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Funcionario WHERE data_admissao <= '2020-01-01'::date AND data_desligamento IS NOT NULL AND data_desligamento > '2020-02-01'::date;
```